# mysql alter on large table to another location?

Tags: mysql

I have a very large (900GB) table in mysql that I need to perform an alter on, but I lack the temp space necessary on my data partition to hold a temp copy of the table (or an extra copy for an online schema change). I have a newly formatted partition just mounted on my box, is there a way I can have an alter write the new table's schema and data to the new partition?

Comment: You can create a new table with the updated schema in the new partition, then insert from the old table into the new table.

Comment: would that work with just a `SELECT * INTO table_new FROM table_old WHERE 1=1` ?

Comment: No. `INSERT INTO table_new SELECT * FROM table_old`

Comment: That assumes the new table has all the same columns in the same order.